# Incorrect return value from tuple with fixed-length array

Tags: solidity

Why does the function below return `[[1, 2], [2, 3]]` instead of the expected `[[1, 2], [3, 4]]`? Tested in browser-solidity.

```
contract Contract {
    function test() constant returns(uint8[2], uint8[2]){
        uint8[2] memory a = [1, 2];
        uint8[2] memory b = [3, 4];
        return (a, b);
    }
}
```

Returning a fixed-length array as the first element in the return tuple appears to throw off the indexed memory location of the following elements, regardless of their type:

```
function test() constant returns(uint8[2], uint8) {
    uint8[2] memory a = [1, 2];
    uint8 b = 3;
    return (a, b); // WRONG: [[1, 2], 2]
}
```

This is also confusing:

```
function test() constant returns(uint8[4], uint8) {
    uint8[4] memory a = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    uint8 b = 3;
    return (a, b); // WRONG: [[1, 2, 3, 4], 2]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I do get the expected values:

```
  [ [ { [String: '1'] s: 1, e: 0, c: [Object] },
      { [String: '2'] s: 1, e: 0, c: [Object] } ],
    [ { [String: '3'] s: 1, e: 0, c: [Object] },
      { [String: '4'] s: 1, e: 0, c: [Object] } ] ]
  [ [ { [String: '1'] s: 1, e: 0, c: [Object] },
      { [String: '2'] s: 1, e: 0, c: [Object] } ],
    { [String: '3'] s: 1, e: 0, c: [ 3 ] } ]
  [ [ { [String: '1'] s: 1, e: 0, c: [Object] },
      { [String: '2'] s: 1, e: 0, c: [Object] },
      { [String: '3'] s: 1, e: 0, c: [Object] },
      { [String: '4'] s: 1, e: 0, c: [Object] } ],
    { [String: '3'] s: 1, e: 0, c: [ 3 ] } ]
```

Comment: What environment? I tested mine in browser solidity.